# Does http_response_code need to be called before any output is sent?

Tags: php

The `http_response_code` function seems like it should work like `header` in that it needs to be called before any output is sent. However, the PHP manual makes no mention of this. Does it work this way? For example, would the following program produce an error?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
http_response_code(404);
?>
</html>
```

If it doesn't, why does `header` work that way but not `http_response_code`?

Comment: "would the following program produce an error?" => why don't you give it a go?

Comment: @JulienLachal but that wouldn't document it for all programmers to see! Plus, I don't have a fast method of executing PHP.

Comment: It sounds to me like you didn't really try to find a way to do it, see http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One of the comments on the PHP manual for this function sums it up nicely:

> http_response_code is basically a shorthand way of writing a http
>   status header, with the added bonus that PHP will work out a suitable
>   Reason Phrase to provide by matching your response code to one of the
>   values in an enumeration it maintains within
>   php-src/main/http_status_codes.h. Note that this means your response
>   code must match a response code that PHP knows about. You can't create
>   your own response codes using this method, however you can using the
>   header method.
>
> In summary - The differences between "http_response_code" and "header"
>   for setting response codes:
>
> 1. Using http_response_code will cause PHP to match and apply a Reason Phrase from a list of Reason Phrases that are hard-coded into the PHP
>      source code.
> 2. Because of point 1 above, if you use http_response_code you must set a code that PHP knows about. You can't set your own custom code,
>      however you can set a custom code (and Reason Phrase) if you use the
>      header method.